# PowerCLI - How to filter datastores by hosts which use them

Tags: powershell, vmware, powershell-3.0, powercli

How would I filter an array of data stores so that I am left with those that have a Host in their ExtensionData.Host array?

I have tried:

```
$Datastores = Get-Datastore
$HostDS = $Datastores | Where-Object{$_.ExtensionData.Host -contains $clusterhost}
```

But this doesn't work, because the host array in `$Datastore.ExtensionData.Host` is not of the datastore objects, but of `DatastoreHostMount` objects. The host mount objects have the IDs of the hosts I want, but I do not know how to compare them against the ID of the `$clusterhost` I am trying to compare them against.

Can I accomplish what I am trying to do here through filtering? I am trying to avoid another call of `Get-Datastore` for efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a key in the object that you need use in your where clause:

```
$hostds = Datastores | where-object{$_.extensiondata.host.key -eq $clusterhost}

Name                               FreeSpaceGB      CapacityGB
----                               -----------      ----------
Name2                            x,xxx.xxx       xx,xxx.xxx
Name1                                x,xxx.xxx       xx,xxx.xxx



$datastores.extensiondata.host  |gm

TypeName: VMware.Vim.DatastoreHostMount

Name        MemberType Definition                                                
----        ---------- ----------                                                
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                            
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()                                         
GetType     Method     type GetType()                                            
ToString    Method     string ToString()                                         
Key         Property   VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference Key {get;set;}          
LinkedView  Property   VMware.Vim.DatastoreHostMount_LinkedView LinkedView {get;}
MountInfo   Property   VMware.Vim.HostMountInfo MountInfo {get;set;}
```

That key had the host name in it...